# Error on npm start using Angular 2 RC version

Tags: angular, npm, typescript-typings

I changed Angular2 beta 15 version to RC version and I got some errors when running application.

```
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(8,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(11,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(12,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(250,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(285,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(292,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(348,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(500,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(563,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(572,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(583,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(592,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(607,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/browser/ambient/es6-shim/index.d.ts(621,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(3,14): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(217,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'flags'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(231,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EPSILON'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(266,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MAX_SAFE_INTEGER'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(273,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'MIN_SAFE_INTEGER'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(583,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(589,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(600,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'size'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(606,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(621,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(635,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(646,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'done'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(647,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'value'.
typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(759,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'prototype'.
```

Can you help me finding how to fix this problem? I am a noob in Angular2.

My json file `typings.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "ambientDependencies": {
        "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `typings.json` file is using a deprecated syntax: it's using `ambientDependencies` instead of `globalDependencies`. Also, the Angular RC doesn't use the `es6-shim` anymore.

Remove your typings folder, update your `typings.json` file and install again.

Update you `typings.json` as follows:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In typings.json Rename:

ambientDevDependencies to globalDevDependencies

ambientDependencies to globalDependencies

Then, at the console:

$ typings install

├── es6-shim (global)

├── angular-protractor (global dev)

├── jasmine (global dev)

└── selenium-webdriver (global dev)